# Inline editing not showing text on typing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement inline editing in my grid but when I click inside a cell, the text I am typing doesn't show up. It also doesn't show that classic text slash (such as this one I am seeing while writing this message). As you can see in the image, the cell is focused but the text I wrote inside it didn't show up, but when I press enter, the cell is updated with its content.

[image]

This is part of my code:

```
<!-- jQuery-UI CSS -->
<link href="../jqGrid/css/layout/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Standard jqGrid CSS -->
<link href="../jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery-UI/jquery-ui-latest.js"></script> 

<!-- jqGrid --> 
<script src="../jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="../jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$("#grid_metadata").jqGrid({    
    url: '../json/jsonMetadata.jsp',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader:{
        root: 'rows', //dados
        page: 'page', //página requisitada
        total: 'total', //total de páginas
        records: 'records' //total de registros
    },      
    pager: '#pager_metadata',
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
    autoencode: true, 
    height: 230,
    width: 550,
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "Campos de Metadados",
    'cellEdit': true,
    'cellsubmit' : 'clientArray',
    editurl: 'clientArray',
    colNames:['ID','Descrição','Valor'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id', width:100, sorttype:"int", sortable: true, editable: false},
        {name:'description', width:940, sortable: true, editable: false},
        {name:'value', width:940, sortable: true, editable: true, editrules:{required:true}}
    ]
}); 

$("#grid_metadata").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager_metadata',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false},
    {}, //edit options
    {}, //add options
    {}, //del options
    {}, //search options
    {} //refresh options
);
```

Comment: It may sound stupid, but what's the `color` and `background-color` for the `input`?

Comment: You should use Developer Tools of Chrome/Internet Explorer/Firefox to examine CSS applied on the INPUT. Either you write with white color over the white or you have some transparency effects.

Comment: Alright, this is the problem. I changed the color attribute dynamically to 'black' and the text showed up. But, how can I change this option in the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the comments above I realized that the text color was white, so that I couldn't see it. I solved it setting `color` CSS attribute like this:

```
afterEditCell: function(rowId, cellName, value, iRow, iCol) {
    var $row = $('#'+iRow+'_value'); // here "value" is the name of your column
    $row.css('color','black');
}
```